# Sort data within string value

Tags: c#, string, linq, sorting, date-format

A string that contains date and integer in specific format: **MM/dd/yyyy (Number)**

```
string strData = "01/23/2017 (5); 01/16/2017 (2);01/24/2017 (6);01/16/2017 (5);01/23/2017 (10)";
```

Based on above I want following:

1. Add Number if date is similar
2. Sorting should be based on date i.e. Ascending

**Expected Output**:

```
strData = "01/16/2017 (7);01/23/2017 (15);01/24/2017 (6)";
```

I know it is possible, if we split on the basis of semicolon and then traverse values using 'for-loop'.

But please suggest me linq solution.

Comment: And also with Linq I am pretty sure that you need to split on the semicolon to make any sense from that string

Comment: Can u give me the sample data for point no 1?

Comment: what do you mean by add number?

Comment: @derloopkat he wants to add the numbers in the parentheses behind the date if the date is the same, basically a grouping of elements

Comment: @MongZhu is right. I want to add the numbers in parenthesis if date is same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
var elems = strData.Split(';') // First, split on semicolon
  .Select(s => s.Trim().Split(' ')) // then remove the extra space at the end of each element, and split again on the space
  .Select(s => new { d = DateTime.ParseExact(s[0], "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), n = int.Parse(s[1].Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "")) }) // here, we create a temp object containing the parsed date and the value
  .GroupBy(o => o.d) // group by date
  .OrderBy(g => g.Key) // then sort
  .Select(g => $"{g.Key:MM'/'dd'/'yyyy} ({g.Sum(a => a.n)})"); // and finally build the resulting string
```

You can then build the final string with:

```
string.Join(";", elems);
```

This answer uses C# 6 interpolated strings. If using an older version of the language, replace `$"{g.Key:MM'/'dd'/'yyyy} ({g.Sum(a => a.n)})"` by `string.Format("{0:MM'/'dd'/'yyyy} ({1})", g.Key, g.Sum(a => a.n))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach

```
string strData = "01/23/2017 (5); 01/16/2017 (2);01/24/2017 (6);01/16/2017 (5);01/23/2017 (10)";
string result = string.Join(";", strData.Split(';')
          .Select(x => new { 
              Date = DateTime.ParseExact(x.Trim().Split()[0], "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
              Count = int.Parse(x.Trim().Split()[1].Trim('(', ')')) })
          .GroupBy(x => x.Date)
          .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
          .Select(x => x.Key.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " (" + x.Sum(y => y.Count) + ")"));
```